# Reduce seconds, minutes and hours using only seconds

Tags: c++, time, operator-overloading, arithmetic-expressions

I want to start coding in c++. I was trying to code a class "Time" with arguments, `Time::Time(int hour, int min, int sec)`, using these arguments.

I was trying to overload the `-=` operator that would allow me to subtract hours, minutes and seconds from my time object.

However, my code doesn't seem to subtract minutes and hours properly. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Here is my code,

```
    Time& Time::operator-=(unsigned int n)
    { sec -= n;
      if (sec < 0)
      { min += sec/60;
        sec %= 60;
        if (min >=60)
         { hour = (hour + min/60) % 24;
            min %= 60;
            }
           }
          return *this;
            }
```

when `hour = 2` , `min = 59`, `sec = 31` for Time t1

using : `t1 -= 400;`

the output is: `02:53:51`

However when I use `t1 -= 3600;`

the output is `02:00:-29`

when it should be `01:59:31`

Comment: Life will be *much* easier if you store the time internally as the total seconds, instead of trying to split it up into hours, minutes seconds.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide an example of your inputs and what you expect and what you get. For example you might have `hour = 2`, `min = 59` and `sec = 31`, and you call `-=` with `400`, and what you get and what you receive.

Comment: What @Shawn said. Separate the value of the time from its representation as text; storing the value as hh:mm:ss is pointless.

Comment: I can't find a reference at the moment, but I think that in C++ `-3569%60` gives -29, not 31.

Comment: `<chrono>` is your friend.